# Is there any call back that hit when we receive firebase notification in background in react native app?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification

I have react native application that targets to both IOS and android. I integrated firebase notifications in my react native mobile application. I face a problem for android when the app is in background then no callback is hit but notification is received in tray from firebase.

I want to add logic for notifications count when app is in background so that when user opens the app he can see that there are 2 or something like new notifications. also want to update the badge count.

I know how to update badge counter or notifications counter as i did when the app is in background then there is call back onNotification that is fired. but i want to hit some code when new notification is received while application is in background.

The code for notifcations

```
      async componentWillUnmount() {
        await this.notificationListener(); 
        await this.notificationOpenedListener();
        await this.messageListener();
      }

     messageListener = async () => {
     // When Notification is Recived and app in fore ground
     this.notificationListener = firebase
      .notifications()      
      .onNotification(async notification => {
        debugger
        console.log("on notification");
        const { title, body } = notification;
        const badgeCount = await firebase.notifications().getBadge();
        debugger
        firebase.notifications().setBadge(badgeCount+1);
        await this.props.clearNotificationCount(badgeCount+1).then(res => {
         debugger
          BadgeAndroid.setBadge(this.props.notifications.Count)
         console.log("BadgeCount is" + badgeCount);
       });

      });

     this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase
     .notifications()
      .onNotificationOpened(async notificationOpen => {
       debugger
       console.log("on open listner");
       const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
       const badgeCount = await firebase.notifications().getBadge();
       debugger
       this.props.setNotificationCount(badgeCount).then(res => {
        //  BadgeAndroid.setBadge(badgeCount)
       });
        firebase.notifications().setBadge(0);
        });
         const notificationOpen = await firebase
       .notifications()
       .getInitialNotification();

      if (notificationOpen) {
       console.log("Notification open");
       console.log(notificationOpen.notification);
       const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
        }
        this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage(message => {
        console.log("on message listner");
          // firebase.notifications().setBadge(2);
       console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
        });
          };

     checkPermission = async () => {
      const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
     if (enabled) {
       await this.getFcmToken();
         } else {
       await this.requestPermission();
       }
      };

       getFcmToken = async () => {
        const fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
         if (fcmToken) {
          let SaveFirebaseTokenEndpoint = ApiEndPoint.SavefireBasetoken;
         let myResponse = await DataAccess.PostSecured(SaveFirebaseTokenEndpoint, {
                DeviceToken: fcmToken
              });
              console.log(fcmToken);
              console.log(myResponse);
            } else {
              //  this.showAlert('Failed', 'No token received');
            }
          };

          requestPermission = async () => {
            try {
              await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
              // User has authorised
            } catch (error) {
              // User has rejected permissions
            }
          };
```

onNotificationOpened() never hits in background

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you can implement a [headless JS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android) to listen for notifs when your app is in [background](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/messaging/receiving-messages#4)-(Optional)(Android-only)-Listen-for-FCM-messages-in-the-background). Note that this will only work on [`data-only`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) Firebase Messages.

There is also a known issue on Android devices, specially the chinese devices with modified OS's that has an aggressive battery saver. You can read more [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-your-push-notifications-never-see-the-light-of-day-3fa297520793/).

On iOS, you cannot show notifs when the app is on background/closed.

Comment: As i am sending notification + data messages from FCM. can they also be received when the app is in background using Headless js in android ?

Comment: No. `data-only` messages are allowed. You need to display the notification manually.